# XHR Issue Angular / Entitity - 502 Error randomly encountered

Tags: javascript, angular, rest

Good Day

A few days ago we started experiencing some odd 502 / CORS errors against our backend out of no where.  Most of the time our API calls will work fine and we'll get a normal response, such as:

access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-expose-headers: Content-Disposition,userrole
access-control-expose-headers: Request-Context
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 561
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Fri, 07 Aug 2020 17:31:34 GMT
expires: -1
pragma: no-cache
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
status: 200
x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
x-powered-by: ASP.NET

Randomly start getting:

content-length: 1477
content-type: text/html
date: Fri, 07 Aug 2020 17:36:06 GMT
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
status: 502

With the response:

[image: Error from Backend]

[image: Network Tab]

The question is could the Frontend cause this kind of problem or can it mitigate it in any possible way?  I'm almost certain this issue lives entirely in the backend, as I don't know see how it's possible for Angular / JavaScript to cause a 502 error in the server, but I'm just covering my bases.

We were using RXJS (6.6.0) for the HTTP Service, with the following code:

```
   httpPost(api: string, data: any): Observable<any> {
     const globalURL = Environment.API_ENDPOINT + api;
     this.buildHeader();
     return this.http.post(globalURL, data, { headers: this.header });
   }
```

For debugging purposes I changed that to use the Fetch API:

```
  httpFetchPost(api: string, data: any) {
    const globalURL = Environment.API_ENDPOINT + api;
    this.buildHeader();

    const fetchOptions = { method: 'POST', headers: this.header, body: JSON.stringify(data) };
    return fetch(globalURL, fetchOptions).then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        const contentType = response.headers.get('Content-Type') || '';
        if (contentType.includes('application/json')) {
          return response.json().catch(error => {
            return Promise.reject(new Error('Invalid JSON: ' + error.message));
          });
        }
        return Promise.reject(new Error('Invalid content type: ' + contentType))
      }
      return Promise.reject(response.statusText);
    }).catch(error => {
      return Promise.reject(error.message);
    });
  }
```

To no benefit.  I'm aware how broad this question is, but the Backend team claims nothing change on their end, and no matter how far back I roll my code, we've tried several weeks, I keep running into the same problem.  This only happens for a couple endpoints, out of the dozens in their controller, so it's no even a constant or consistent issue.

Thanks

Comment: Definitely an issue with the downstream backend server if you ask me. Might be a volume thing, disk space, memory. We’ve seen this before and usually turns out to be a server health issue. I’d start by analyzing the logfiles.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll forward that to the backend team.